# Help me identify an SMD diode?

Tags: identification, surface-mount

I think it is a Zener diode but there is no marking except a '5' and five parallel lines (polarity?).

The component is on a Dumbo2 Rev2.1 motherboard for the Ideapad Z710.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. The easy way is to power up the board and measure the voltage across this diode.

Comment: Thank you for you suggestion. Unfortunately the component is on the "wrong" side of the motherboard. I can't access it to measure the voltage.

Comment: What the 5 number stand for? on the smd code i found  -5 =5 and >5 but no 5 lines over the number 5

Comment: I do not understand. You were able to get a clear close up view, but you cannot get probes to it? The number 5 by itself means nothing. These parts are too tiny to silkscreen a full part number or part code on them.

Comment: Correct to get a clear view I needed to dismantle the laptop and remove the motherboard. To power it  I have to assemble the laptop back and then the diode is no more accessible

Comment: Solder on a pair of fine gauge insulated wires to the diode, 22 to 26 awg will do, and run them outside the case so you can mostly close it up. There is always a trick to diagnose a problem.

Comment: If you can trace what else is connected to that "diode" it'll help you narrow it down further. A quick check with a multimeter(if you have one handy) will tell if it's even a diode in the first place - doesn't always work depending on what else is connected to it.

Comment: Unsolder it, bias it with ~10 mA and find out what it is and if zener diode, what voltage.

Comment: Thank you all for your suggestions. I will use the tricks and take a wider picture of the area.

Answer (score 1):

Probably RB751V-40 Schottky diode, datasheet: http://www.rohm.com/web/in/datasheet/RB751V-40

Comment: That is great - Thank you very much to all of you - this just shows the power of the community.